# How do I make JavaFX work on mac(Visual Studio Code)?

Tags: java, macos, javafx, visual-studio-code

So I tried making a JavaFX application on my Mac, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
I heard that JavaFX is bundled with JDK.
I am using the latest JDK and Java.
I use Visual Studio Code. Sometimes I also use Eclipse.
My operating system is macOS Catalina version 10.15.3.

So here's the problem:
When I try to import JavaFX, it gives me an error.
The error says: The import JavaFX cannot be resolved
Why does this happen and how can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe the documentation helps you. There is no specific section for VS Code but I think you will get the idea. https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ And your assumption that JavaFX is bundled with the JDK is wrong since JDK 11. JavaFX is just one additional external dependency.

Comment: Thank you for adding a comment! I

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX is NOT bundled with the Java JDK anymore, the JFX library is a separate library that must be downloaded from openjfx.io and linked to your project.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for letting me know!!